# How to prevent AngularJS sorting parameters in a GET request in a $resource action?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

My resource is:

```
angular.module('myApp.services')
    .factory('MyResource', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('http://example.org', {}, {});
    }]);
```

How I do a GET request is:

```
MyResource.get({z: 5, a: 4});
```

The URL generated by AngularJS is:

> http://example.org/?a=4&z=5

How I want the URL to be is:

> http://example.org/?z=5&a=4

Any solutions?

P.S. I thought using an interceptor could do the trick but there is no method for intercepting a request, but there are optional methods called `response` and `responseError`. This is because interceptors for $resource and $http are different. See: [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) and [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: You can't guarantee the order of your object's properties [by design](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order).

Comment: but why you need this? order in parameters not matter

Comment: @Bigood thanks for your comment. That may be the reason why AngularJS sorts the parameters alphabetically.

Comment: @Grundy In fact, the order of parameters doesn't matter for me. But the API I rely on forces this behavior for some endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. I simply prefer this for any Service call

```
var app=angular.module("Test",[]);

app.service('somename', function ($http) {

this.GetData = function (z,a) {
    return $http.get('http://example.org/?z='+z+'&a='+a);
}
});

app.controller("demo",function($scope,somename){

var d=somename.GetData(4,5);

});
```

Comment: Thanks. Good workaround, but not the best solution :( Because it uses $http instead of $resource and you build up the url manually, which is hard in most cases. $resource is a good abstraction of $http for RESTful services and gives many advantages.

Comment: But, in case I feel running out of time, that's the exact approach I would try ;)